# Литература по Embedded

Tags: embedded

Доброго времени суток знатокам ! Я сам из Украины, закончил местный ВУЗ, и хочу уйти с головой в Embedded даже не смотря что это не перспективно и зарплаты значительно ниже от WEB-разработчиков, но так сложилось что не люблю я копаться в тоннах HTML-кода или JS просто WEB мне не по душе, мне нравиться работать на уровне ядра ОС и железячки. Вопрос таков, кто-нибуть знает толковую литературу по этой теме ? Искал про контроллеры ARM (с которыми хочу поработать) так либо всякий бред качаю, либо никто разумного ничего не написал, ничего про Embedded толкового не нашёл, может кто-то ещё что либо подскажет (в какую сторону двигаться, но только в Embedded направлении) ! Короче люди я буду ждать любой совет, ресурс, подсказку, направление, очень хочу всё это охватить, познать и поработать !!!

Comment: если коротко, то google.com, yandex.ru, на крайний случай, bing.com, должны помочь

Comment: Случайно вспомнил. Вещь старая, конечно, для 8051. Michael Pont. Programming Embedded System. Ищется в и-нете. Программы на C. Ну, и как писал @beerko -- datasheet'ы... (Да, это слайды курса. Книга-то называется Embedded C, но я её не видел)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Дружище поверь, ты будешь плеваться потом долго и упорно что не стал заниматься как я вебом, а ушел как я в железо. Для начала, Должен знать Си просто изумительно, asm по ходу будешь догонять, есть есть с++ знания. Если будешь знать что есть транзисторы и тп вообще прекрасно (разбираться в схеме) вообще прекрасно купи себе отладку недорогую, Например на LPC1111(14) Выглядит отладка так (http://im6-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=599861828-08-72&n=21 ) lpcexpresso. Прочитай даташит к процу и юзермануал, разберись, немного страниц 800 английским. Читай как работать с UART,SPI,I2C,RTC и другой периферией. На отладке есть термодатчик и еще что-то с чем можно повзаимодействовать. Покупай или дербань сотовые достовай из них дисплее ищи инфу и выводи что нибудь на экран. Если будет у тебя проц с USB, попробуй и в нем разобраться. Как поймешь что к чему, Купи получше проц и SWD или JTAG отладчик, GSM, GPS модули,SD карту, сделай например проект типа GPS маячек. Можешь попробовать проект реализовать на RTOS, и использовать многопоточность.

К изучению как минимум http://books.tr200.ru/v.php?id=804485
Качай с сайтов примеры кода работы с периферией, смотри что к чему.

Если тяжелой книга окажется, тогда уходи в RISC процессоры AVR или PIC(16)(24)

Comment: А если ему понравятся шестиногие контроллеры (PIC(10))? И какие AVR Вы советуете? Их уже несколько лет как две архитектуры

Comment: Все зависит от задачи которую нужно делать. На PIC10 у меня например у меня сделан менеджер+супервизор питания, управляю им с главного мк.
Также на 10тке делал экономайзер холостого хода, для 2х цилиндрового двигателя.

А из AVR честно уже сто лет не возился, сам начинал с ATMEGA16, потом ATMEGA8, потом были пикушки.

Почему первыми были AVRки, да потому что там программатор простой из LPT 5 проводков. Это было 5 лет назад. Из атмеловоского последнее с чем возился было AT91SAM9G45, но тут понятно уже Linuxом пахнет.

Comment: Ну AT91SAM -- это уж никак не avr. А шестиногие PIC'и -- они же вроде не дешевле avr tiny? А самая маленькая "крошка" -- 8 ног. И может сейчас уже не так, но вроде PIC 16F и ниже -- это преимущественно ассемблер?

Comment: PIC10 последний раз покупал ровно за 10 рублей. Аvr tiny по моему, даже более функциональны чем PIC10.

Comment: Учитывая, что в 21 веке у крошек флеш начинается с 2K, а RAM (кажется) со 128 (+32 рег.), то да. У tiny25 (осьминог) вроде ещё и таймер суперскоростной...

Но 10 рублей -- это круто.

Comment: У авр самая маленькая крошка шестиногая, а ля tiny10. Но они в России редки и покупаются фирмами на заказ через конторы типа Компела.

Comment: @Алексей Сонькин Я уже лет 5 не слежу за такими новостями, поэтому про них не знал. Спасибо. Прикольно. Отрезали нижнюю половину регистров, но добавили 32б SRAM. Хитрый народ -- финны.

Comment: Пессимизм в словах, на самом деле ковыряния железа очень доходное дело, если понимать что к чему.

Answer (score 1):

Ну Embedded можно не только на С/asm. Есть там небольшое пространство и для Java. Позырь в сторону [Java Embedded](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/embedded/overview/index.html) или [Java Card](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/embedded/card/overview/index.html)

Comment: Там пространство есть для чего угодно. Во-первых это, ясно дело, HDL'и, ибо одним софтом не так сытно. Во-вторых, даже в нише почти самых маленьких есть [Ocaml](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaml_for_pic/web/index.php?id=OCAPIC) или [.NET](http://netduino.com/), например. Ну а уж под ARM'ы так вообще выбирай-нехочу.

Comment: @drdaeman ну что касается ссылки по .NET, то это arm'ы, ocapic -- да 8-бит PIC'и (18F -- семейство самых больших восьмибитных PIC'ов. Глубже не смотрел, но на такой мелочёвке автоматическое управление памятью должно быть достаточно узким местом.

Comment: Упс, про .NET таки наврал, ардуина-то на ATmega'е, ну и проассоциировалось... А про ARM ОП сам писал.

Answer (score 1):

А с английским как? Если хорошо, то для начала очень советую "Making Embedded Systems", Elecia White и "The Art of Designing Embedded Systems", Jack Ganssle
Можно почитать довольно обширную тему на этом [форуме](http://forum.shelek.ru/index.php/topic,26526.0.html).
Из русскоязычного, можно почитать книги от М. Предко, "Устройства управления роботами" и другие (но надо делать скидку на время, к примеру, те же PIC-и нынче "не в моде" (хотя и всё ещё применяются) ).

Практически все книги есть в сети.

Не книги, но лично мне кажется полезным: сборник статей на [этом](http://www.pic24.ru/doku.php/osa/articles/encoding_without_errors) сайте, а так-же курсы на edx ("Embedded systems - shape the world", "Circuits and Electronics " и "Electronic Interfaces: Bridging the Physical and Digital Worlds")